# Knowing if this equation is linear or not and how to express it as a linear equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So im trying to solve a physsics problem and involves solving a system. One of the system´s equations reads:
$ (6x^5+4bx^3+2cx)exp(ax6+bx5+cx^2+d)=C$, where C and x are constants and the system/equation variables are a,b,c,d.

I tried to solve it with non linear computacional methods. But my professor today sent me an e-mail saying that this a linear system of equations. Not wanting to be rude( and I dont have a close relatioship with him) I do not think this is a linear equation. Am I missing something? I can't seem to be able to express the equation as: $aC_1+bC_2+c_C3+dC_4$ = C.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the perfect answer, but here's what I think could be done to approach this with linear systems:

Take p^q = C

LHS =RHS in the following cases :
1) p =C, q = 1
2) p = 1/C, q = - 1

These represent a system of linear equations. However, it is the general solution since it does not include all the cases ( only the simple ones ) but i think the solution will satisfy the conditions, so this should be the right direction